# Render multiple components in React Router

Tags: javascript, meteor, react-router, reactjs

I'm used to application layouts with multiple yield areas, i.e. for content area and for top bar title. I'd like to achieve something similar in React Router. For example:

```
<Router>
  <Route path="/" component = { AppLayout }>
    <Route path="list"
           component = { ListView }
           topBarComponent = { ListTopBar }/>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

*AppLayout:*

```
<div className="appLayout box">
  <div className="appLayout topBar">
    { -- display ListTopBar here -- }
  </div>
  <div className="appLayout content">
    { -- display ListView here -- }
  </div>     
</div>
```

Both child components should receive the same props.

How can I approach this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To passe multiple component you can do like this :

```
<Route path="groups" components={{main: Groups, sidebar: GroupsSidebar}} />
<Route path="users" components={{main: Users, sidebar: UsersSidebar}}>
```

See the doc here : 
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/API.md#named-components

Comment: Link link is broken. It should be: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/API.md#named-components

Answer (score 17):

In v4, according to the [docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md#render-func), you can render multiple components like this:

```
<Route path='/some-path' render={() =>
  <Fragment>
    <FirstChild />
    <SecondChild />
  </Fragment>
} />
```

Comment: Shouldn't the prop for this be `path='/popular'` instead of `to='/popular'` ?

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using div's you can use Fragments.
`

```
<Route path='/some-path' render={props =>
  <Fragment>
    <Child 1/>
    <Child 2/>
  </Fragment>
} />
```

`

Answer (score 5):

You can also use Array in latest versions of React-router-dom;

> ```
> <Route path="groups" element={[<Component1/>,<Component2/>]} />
> ```

Will work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

To render multiple components you can do this:

```
<Route 
    path="/EditEmployee/:id"  
    render={(props) => 
        <div>
            <NavMenu />
            <EditEmployee {...props} />
        </div> 
    } 
/>
```

Here I'm passing parameter to specific conponent.

Answer (score 2):

//this is the simplest method to render multiple components and it works for me

```
<Router>
  <Route path="/">
       <ListView />
       <ListTopBar /> 
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
 <Route path='/' element={<><Header /> <Home /></>} />
```

This worked for me in the latest react router dom v6

Answer (score 1):

Another method is within the render method of route multiple passed components can be created using react.createElement

```
<Route render ={(props)=>React.createElement(Component1, {...props}},
                     React.createElement(Component2, {...props}}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to wrap the multiple components in a `<Fragment>` or a `<div>` as a parent element.

```
  return (
    < Router>
      <div className="App" >
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/'
            element={
              <Fragment>
                  < NavBar />
                  < NewsLetterCard />
                  < TestimonialsCard />
                  < ServicesCard />
                  < ContactsCard />
                  < Footer />
              </Fragment>
            }
          />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For v6, where you are using Routes instead of Switch to render your components. This works:

```
<Router>
<Routes>
<Route path='/' element={<><Child1/> <Child2/></>} />
</Routes>
</Router>
```

But for v5, this works:

```
<Router>
<Switch>
<Route path="/">
   <Child1/>
   <Child2/> 
</Route>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seem to work for me, I needed to add canvas animation component as background under homepage ("/") only:

```
import Page from 'pages/Page';
import Blog from 'pages/Blog';
import Post from 'pages/Post';
import Category from 'pages/Category';
import CanvasParticles from 'components/canvas/CanvasParticles';
```

...

```
<Routes>
  {['/', '/:slug'].map((path, index) => {
  return path === '/' ? (
   <Route
    exact
    path={path}
    element={[<CanvasParticles />, <Page />]}
    key={index}
   />
  ):(
   <Route path={path} element={<Page />} key={index} />
  );
 })}
 <Route exact path="/blog" element={<Blog />}></Route>
 <Route path="/blog/:slug" element={<Post />}></Route>
 <Route path="/category/:slug" element={<Category />}></Route>
</Routes>
```

Answer (score -1):

[click on this you can view a image v6 feature :  this is the simplest method to render multiple components and it works for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjiHC.png)

Main Concept is to you should wrap with element
<Route path="/" element={<>  </>}
or
wrap with in Fragment
<Route path="/" element={  }

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32221645)