# Render multiple elements in React Router v6.+

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I need the answer to this question: [Render multiple components in React Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37342997/render-multiple-components-in-react-router) but for the newer version of react-router-dom (I'm using v6.0.2)

the older version of router-dom would work like this:

```
<Route path="/">
 <Header/>
 <Home/>
</Route>
```

while the new one looks like this:

```
<Route exact path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
```

I'm not sure how to add the Header as well

Comment: Just an FYI, `Route` components no longer take an `exact` prop in RRDv6. All routes are exactly matched by default now.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try wrap them in a fragment

```
<Route exact path="/" element={<><Header/><Home/></>}/>
```

Comment: Thank you! Simple and effective.

Answer (score 3):

I ran in to the same issue, but also needed one page to get data from the parent element.

```js
<Route path="/" element={<><Header/><Home children={<HomeDataProvider/>}/></>} />
```

Answer (score 1):

try this if u want to add two or more component just put them inside of fragment tag

<Route exact path="/" element={<></>}/>

Comment: Hi @ramkishan-saini , Welcome to StackOverflow. The same answer is already given and accepted by the author. Please consider adding an answer only when your answer brings something new to the table.

Also, user mini-Markdown formatting while writing a code block.

Answer (score 1):

for Render multiple components in React Router for the newer version of react-router-dom (I'm using v6.5.0)

```
<Route path="/" element={ 
        <>
          < AddTodo addTodo={ addTodo }/>
          <Todos todos={todos} onDelete={onDelete}/>
        </>}>
      </Route>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap multiple components in the fragment tag. This is how I did this:

```
<Route path="/" element={<><Header/><Home></>} </Route>
```