# routing in react issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am trying to create a basic web page in react which has some `<h1>` text and two links - one to login page and other to register page. here is the code->

index.js

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));


root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/register/header';
import RegistrationForm from './components/register/registrationForm'
import { Route, Link, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (

  <div className="App">
    <br></br>
    <h1>Welcome to my website!</h1>  
      <br></br>
      <br></br>
      <br></br>

      <Link to="/register">Register</Link> 
    
    

    <Route exact path="/register" component={RegistrationForm} />  

    </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

what i want is when i click on register button, i want the `Header` and `RegistrationForm` component to load and `App` component to disappear.

This code is not working. i get an empty screen.

if i remove these lines

```
<Link to="/register">Register</Link> 
<Route exact path="/register" component={RegistrationForm} />
```

the `App` component works fine. can someone help?

---EDIT---

App.js

```
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./components/register/header";
import RegistrationForm from "./components/register/registrationForm";
import Home from "./components/home/home";
import { Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Home />

      <Link to="/register">Register</Link>

      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/register"
          element={
            <>
              <Header />
              <RegistrationForm />
            </>
          }
        />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Home.js

```
import React from "react";
function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <br></br>

      <h1>Welcome to my website!</h1>

      <br></br>
      <br></br>
      <br></br>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;

//end
```

Comment: Did you include your actual <BrowserRouter/> component? Looking at the docs i think you are missing the wrapping <Router> component (https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App.js

```
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./components/register/header";
import RegistrationForm from "./components/register/registrationForm";
import Home from "./components/home/home";
import { Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />

        <Route
          path="/register"
          element={
            <>
              <Header />
              <RegistrationForm />
            </>
          }
        />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should wrap the app with `Router` :

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));


root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

and in App.js you are missing `Routes` wrapping `Route`:

```
import { Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
function App {
  *other code*
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" component={Home} /> 
    <Route path="/register" component={RegistrationForm} />   
  </Routes>
}
```

Comment: this works but it shows only the link on my page but when i click on it, it doesnt load to `RegistrationForm` component and neither does the `App` component disappear.

Comment: `<Route exact path="/register" element={<RegistrationForm />} />` this is working but how do i load multiple components and how to remove `App` component.

Comment: Try removing every `exact` it is not supported in react router v6

Comment: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37342997/render-multiple-components-in-react-router` i found an answer here which helped me to render multiple components. now all i need is to remove the home component on loading of register component. see the update in question.

Comment: Why don't you add Home inside Routes? Like this `<Route path="/" component={Home} />  `

Comment: You`re welcome! Consider accepting the answer if it helped you so other people can benefit too!

Answer (score 0):

Router, Switch and Header are missing.

You need something like this :

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

render(
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```js
<div className="App">
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/">
      <Home/>
    </Route>
    <Route exact path="/register">
      <Header />
      <RegistrationForm/>
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</div>
```

```js
<div className="Home">
  <br />
  <h1>Welcome to my website!</h1>  
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <Link to="/register">Register</Link> 
</div>
```

I think you will need to make a second Switch like this to share your header between pages except Home :

```js
<div className="App">
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/">
      <Home/>
    </Route>
    <Route path="/">
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/register">
          <RegistrationForm/>
        </Route>
        {/* Other routes with the Header */}
      </Switch>
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</div>
```

Comment: `switch` seems deprecated. i think.

Comment: My example is in v5, but in v6 it seems you can just replace it by <Routes/>

Comment: tried it not working.

Comment: Can you check S.Marx idea. that is working but component is not loading

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#advantages-of-route-element
In that you new version, you don't need to set a second Routes like the second Switch. Maybe a part of the probleme.
For your edit, you need to put Home in a Routes > Route to make it disappeared on page change